# Ant SCP task through SSH connection

Tags: java, ant, ssh, scp

I want to be able to transfer my application to the development server but in order to access it I first have to ssh to an SSH gateway and then ssh into the internal network to the appropriate server. I can do this with WinSCP using the Tunnel option, I know that ant supports SCP tasks but does it support it over another ssh connection?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an ugly suggestion, but could you use the scp task to get your app deployed to the gateway and then use the sshexec task to run a script on the gateway to scp your application to the next server?

Comment: nope, the gateway is set up in such a fashion that when you connect it gives you some custom shell which asks you to enter a machine name of the internal list and then automatically connects you to the internal machine

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is not exactly new, I found myself in a similar situation today. My goal is to upload files and run commands on a remote server to which I have to tunnel (through another server). **And it is possible with ant!**

The `sshsession` only creates a **tunnel** that you can use for the tasks within. The tasks within are not automatically run on the remote server but you can use the `sshexec` task together with the **tunnel** to achieve that. Also the `scp` task can now upload through the tunnel to the remote server. Here is an example:

```
<sshsession host="${jumphost}" port="22" username="${user}" password="${password}" trust="true">
    <localtunnel lport="${localTunnelPort}" rhost="${targethost}" rport="22"/>
    <sequential>
        <!-- run a command on the remote server (here mkdir) -->
        <sshexec host="localhost" port="${localTunnelPort}" username="${user.param}" password="${password.param}" command="mkdir ${home}/foobar" trust="true" />
        <!-- upload a file to the remote server -->
        <scp port="${localTunnelPort}" file="test_file.txt" todir="${user.param}:${password.param}@localhost:${home}/foobar/" trust="true" />
    </sequential>
</sshsession>
```